# Merge two maps with same keys in java and add the value together

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have data like this:

```
a 0020
b 0010
c 0030
c 0400
a 0100
```

Since they are in pairs I used `HashMap` to retrieve them. Now I have to add them together and the outcome should come with one key and add the value together, like this:

```
a 0120
b 0010
c 0430
```

Example of string that I retrieve the data:
SSSSSSSSSASSSSSSSSSSSS0020   // its not same as actual data but the code is actual.
I used A is key and 0020 as value

```
Map<String, String> col = new HashMap<>();
try {
    File file = new File("file address.txt");
    Scanner cmd = new Scanner(file);
    String num = "";
    String Name = "";

    while (cmd.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = cmd.nextLine();
        if (line.charAt(9) == 'A') {
            num = line.substring(23, 28); 
            Name = line.substring(29, 34);
            col.put(Name, num);     
        }
        Iterator it2 = col.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it2.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, String> entry = (Entry<String, String>) it2.next();
            System.out.println("name = " + entry.getKey() + " and value= " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something? Post your code.

Comment: Since you know how to `put()` a key/value pair, and you know how to `get()` the value of a key, and presumable know how to use the `+` addition operator, what is stopping you from getting any existing value, adding the two numbers, and putting the updated value back?

Comment: So do you have one map or several maps?  How did you use `HashMap` to retrieve values from the "pairs"?  How do you represent the pairs, are they provided at input as a list/ array, will you show some code?

Comment: SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS00200A000000000000  I used substring to get A as key and 00200 as value. I then used hashmap to print them. Now I have to organize them based on key and add total of value.  Map<String, String> col = new HashMap<>();
try {
 File file = new File("file address.txt");
 Scanner cmd = new Scanner(file);
 char entryType = 'A';
 String num = "";
 String Name = "";

Comment: while (cmd.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = cmd.nextLine();
  if (line.charAt(9) == entryType) {
   num = line.substring(23, 28);
   Name = line.substring(29, 34);
   col.put(Name, num);  }
  Iterator it2 = col.entrySet().iterator();
  while (it2.hasNext()) {
   Entry<String, String> entry = (Entry<String, String>) it2.next();
   System.out.println("name = " + entry.getKey() + " and valuem= " + entry.getValue());
  }}} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: @Morid, please edit your question and add the code in the question itself, thanks!

Comment: @AlexRudenko I appreciate if you can take a look in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the values in `col` map should be of numeric type to allow for arithmetic operations, or another map `Map<String, Integer>` should be created to store the results of calculations.

Also, there's no need to have a nested loop to calculate the sums while reading the data because the calculation results will be incorrect.

There are several ways to accumulate the sums in the map per key.

1. Use method [`Map::compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```java
Map<String, Integer> col = new HashMap<>(); // changed value type to Integer
// ...
Integer number = 0;
while (cmd.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = cmd.nextLine();
    if (line.charAt(9) == 'A') {
        number = Integer.valueOf(line.substring(23, 28)); 
        Name = line.substring(29, 34);
        col.compute(Name, (key, prev) -> (prev == null ? 0 : prev) + number);     
    }
    // no need for nested loop
}

// print map contents
col.forEach((name, sum) -> System.out.print("%s %04d%n", name, sum));
```

2. Use method [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) along with [`Integer::sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#sum-int-int-) which can be replaced with a lambda `(sum, val)-> sum + val`:

```java
Integer number = 0;
while (cmd.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = cmd.nextLine();
    if (line.charAt(9) == 'A') {
        number = Integer.valueOf(line.substring(23, 28)); 
        Name = line.substring(29, 34);
        col.merge(Name, number, Integer::sum);     
    }
}
// print map contents
col.forEach((name, sum) -> System.out.print("%s %04d%n", name, sum));
```

Answer (score 0):

While adding pairs to your `HashMap`, you can check if the key already exists and if so, then just sum the value in your `HashMap` with the value from pair.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); // your HashMap
String key;                                     // pair key
int value;                                      // pair value

if(map.keySet().contains(key)) {
    map.put(key, map.get(key) + value);
} else {
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I used substring to retrieve the data as key and value. when I use integer it give me error. I put the code in comment. I am sorry this is my first time and I might missed up. lol